# Prometheus and ActiveMQ Integration

Tags: prometheus, activemq-classic, activemq-artemis

I want to show the metrics of ActiveMQ on Promtheus/Grafana and generate the Alerts using Prometheus AlertManager.

Kindly suggest any option to scrape the ActiveMQ metrics in Prometheus.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're using ActiveMQ "Classic" then you'll need to use the [Prometheus JMX Exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter).

However, if you're using ActiveMQ Artemis then you can use the [Prometheus metrics plugin implementation](https://github.com/jbertram/artemis-prometheus-metrics-plugin). General information about exporting metrics in ActiveMQ Artemis can be found in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/metrics.html).

A sample Grafana dashboard is available [here](https://github.com/artemiscloud/grafana).

Comment: Thank you for all of your hard work on so many aspects of Artemis. May I ask if there are any pre-configured Grafana dashboards that work with the plugin you have mentioned? I've installed the plugin, and the metrics are there. Even if there is no existing dashboard, the metrics are fairly self-explanatory and building a dashboard should not be hard. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Basic ActiveMQ metrics like number of Queues, number of Messages in a Queue etc can be achieved using a JMX Exporter.

http://blog.klocwork.com/open-source/monitoring-java-applications-prometheus-grafana-part-1/

Comment: When using this method, I am unable to use artemis die present in bin folder, getting error "Address already in use"